# Unix equivalent of windows terminal server options?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-terminal-services

I want to replace Windows terminal server mostly due to cost reasons license cost for 2100 users goes out of roof.

The end-user is all windows but I want a jump server that is UNIX based , I have some experience with VNC but I don't want options exists in UNIX to run a terminal services for 2100 users. Some of the basic requirement for such a setup be:-

- use of browser to access web based application
- Restrict or limit desktop application based upon user authorization.
- Supporting concurrent users for about 1200 per server.

Please let me know how should I go about.

Comment: If the application to be used is web based, why bother with a terminal server? Every desktop already has a serviceable web browser.

Comment: While product recommendations are off topic, you should have mentioned your budget.

Comment: Also consider security requirements....From my memory, the freebie VNC is not very secure.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at x2go (www.x2go.org) or xrdp. x2go uses its own x2goclient which is part of many linux didtributions and also availlable for windows and mac clients. x2go supports passthrough of local usb devices and printers and sound but no hw accelerated 3d graphics and no good video performance.